# I want to insert multiple rows of data, but I can only insert one row at a time

Tags: oracle, dbeaver

```
INSERT INTO MINE.PLC_HELP_DESK_TB (ITEM_ID,TOTAL_QUANTITY,DATE_ENTERED,USERNAME,OLD_VALUES,NEW_VALUES,CHANGED_BY,CHANGED_ON,STOCK_RECIEVED) VALUES
     (10,99,NULL,NULL,'ITEM_NAME:Milk DATE_ENTERED:20-AUG-12 USERNAME: LOC_ID:10 STOCK_RECIEVED: DUMYCOL1:','ITEM_NAME:Milk DATE_ENTERED:22-AUG-12 USERNAME: LOC_ID:10 STOCK_RECIEVED: DUMYCOL1:','MAMA',TIMESTAMP'2012-08-22 12:12:52.0',NULL),

     (11,20,NULL,NULL,'ITEM_NAME:Sugar DATE_ENTERED:20-AUG-12 USERNAME: LOC_ID:10 STOCK_RECIEVED: DUMYCOL1:','ITEM_NAME:Sugar DATE_ENTERED:22-AUG-12 USERNAME: LOC_ID:10 STOCK_RECIEVED: DUMYCOL1:','MAMA',TIMESTAMP'2012-08-22 12:12:52.0',NULL),

     (17,149,NULL,NULL,'ITEM_NAME:B Bags DATE_ENTERED:20-AUG-12 USERNAME: LOC_ID:10 STOCK_RECIEVED: DUMYCOL1:','ITEM_NAME:B Bags DATE_ENTERED:22-AUG-12 USERNAME: LOC_ID:10 STOCK_RECIEVED: DUMYCOL1:','MAMA',TIMESTAMP'2012-08-22 12:12:52.0',NULL),

     (19,1,NULL,NULL,'ITEM_NAME:Sun Lig DATE_ENTERED:17-AUG-12 USERNAME: LOC_ID:10 STOCK_RECIEVED: DUMYCOL1:','ITEM_NAME:Sun Lig DATE_ENTERED:22-AUG-12 USERNAME: LOC_ID:10 STOCK_RECIEVED: DUMYCOL1:','MAMA',TIMESTAMP'2012-08-22 12:12:52.0',NULL);
```

I am getting an error when running this query, I have lots of data that I need to insert, but it is only allowing me to insert one row at a time, I would like to insert multiple rows at once, but I get that error.

It works when I run it one row at a time but it give an error when I run more rows.

I have tried SELECT 1 FROM DUAL;
but it still gives the same error

Comment: this is one query

Comment: https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/questions/insert_rows.php

Comment: wow, this looks like a bad design, storing multiple attributes in the same column.

Comment: Google oracle INSERT ALL syntax